# Regex matching everything except what is between [ ... ]

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for two Regex which given a string like the following one:

`I want [I]  cAptUre this [don't] number [want to] 9 and [be captured] this Word`

- (A)  return only the string inside each `[]` (brackets included). I've solved this with `\[(.*?)\]`
- (B) return everything except what is inside `[]` (brackets excluded from the end result). So the opposite of the previous one.

Expected result:

- (A) `["[I]", "[don't]", "[want to]", "[be captured]"]`
- (B) `"I want CaptUre this number 9 and this Word"`

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe search for ].*[ instead of [.*]

Comment: You may want to recognize everything from `^` to `[`, everything from `]` to `[`, everything from `]` to `$`

Comment: For your example, do you wish construct the array `["[I]", "[don't]", "[want to]", "[be capture]"]`  and the string `"  cAptUre this  number  9 and "`? Whenever you give an example it's helpful to show the desired result.

Comment: I don't know if C# supports `(*SKIP)` & `(*FAIL)` verbs, but, if it does, [this](https://regex101.com/r/qZfTqi/1) does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have altered source string a bit to include edge cases:

`[We] I want [I]  cAptUre this [don't] number [want to] 9 and [be captured] this Word [89]`

```
var without_brackets = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\[.*?\]\s*", " ").Trim();
var in_brackets = string.Join(" ", Regex.Matches(s, @"\[(.*?)\]")
                        .OfType<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value));

WriteLine($"Without brackets: '{without_brackets}'");
WriteLine($"In brackets: '{in_brackets}'");

// Output:
// Without brackets: 'I want cAptUre this number 9 and this Word'
// In brackets:      'We I don't want to be captured 89'
```

#### Without brackets

The pattern searches for the brackets *and* all spaces to both sides - and replaces them with a space. I used `*` quantifier for `\s` in order to include edge cases when there can be words in brackets at the end and at the start of the string. Also, `Trim` is required to remove extra spaces for edge cases.

#### With brackets

It's all simple - search for anything in brackets and `Join` them.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning (A), you can use a [Match.Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netcore-3.1) and the pattern `@"(\[[^]]+\])"`  suggested by Gilles Quenot.
Concerning (B), you can use [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions) to replace your text brackets:

```
var input = "I want[I]  cAptUre this[don't] number [want to] 9 and [be captured] this Word";
var pattern = @"(\[[^]]+\])";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The output is

```
I want  cAptUre this number  9 and  this Word
```

If you want to avoid duplicate white spaces in the output you can replace them too:

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"(\s\s+)", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this for the first requirement :

```
(\[[^]]+\])
```

Check https://regex101.com/r/NdmSRF/1

For the second requirement, not sure a regex alone can do this, but [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can do it:

```
$ sed -E 's/\[[^]]+\]//g' file
I want   cAptUre this  number  9 and  this Word
```